# Using Delimeter (Mariadb ) in grafana

Tags: mariadb, grafana

I'm a newbie with Grafana 6.4, using Mariadb 10.3.

Below SQL could work at the workbench:

```sql
DELIMITER //
BEGIN NOT ATOMIC
    DECLARE groupType INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT SHOWORDER INTO groupType FROM dba.VW_IOT_TBLWIPAPSGROUP3 WHERE GROUP_NUMBER='20181224150734';
    IF (groupType < 10) THEN 
    select * from dba.VW_IOT_TBLWIPAPSGROUP3;
    ELSE
    select GROUP_NAME from dba.VW_IOT_TBLWIPAPSGROUP3;
    END IF;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

but will get an error in Grafana:

```
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //
BEGIN NOT ATOMIC
    DECLARE groupType INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT SH' at line 1
```

Any suggestion for this case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DELIMITER is not part of SQL, but a client feature.

In mysql command line client and workbench the semicolon `;` is used to recognize when a statement should be sent to the server. This will not work if you write a function or stored procedure which contains a semicolon, in this case you need to replace the semicolon by another delimiter.

If you don't use mysql command line client or workbench, you don't need the delimiter. So you need to remove 1st and last 2 lines from your SQL statement.